# Mysql Access Denied for user when usign IONIC, but works with Postman

Tags: ionic-framework

I created a PWA with ionic/angular. An API in PHP to set/retrieve the data.

In my localhost: everything works fine.
I move the API to the server: With Postman, all the calls works fine
Now I change the URL in Ionic from the localhost to the internet server: Doesn’t work

> Error message: “SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ‘userXX’@‘xxx.xx.xxx.249’ (using password: YES)”

I checked the MySQL permissions in the server, no problem.

Why with Postman it works, in the same server address, but not in Ionic?

Comment: The only thing that will differ between ionic and postman is headers and maybe https

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, at the end adding the IP source to MySQL as remote access host fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dharman for the editing, I'm not English native, not an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding the IP as remote access host in Mysql. But still weird than Postman works. And yes, @Mostafa, it pass from http to https. I'll investigate.